# Buttons in "Translation Management" tab are disabled for Regional Editors?

Tags: tridion

We're using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, with SDL World Server, Translation Manager and Workflow.
We have Regional_editor group and they have "Translation Management" and "Translation Configuration" rights with R-W ( Read - Write ) at the source publication and target publication.

The Editor is able to send items to translation and see the translation job in Translation node. So far so good.

Our issue comes when they select a item and click the "Translation Management" tab in the ribbon. Now Retry Sending , Retry Retrieving, Send to translation buttons appears disable to these Regional_editor group.

Any thoughts, is there any config/setup missing?

Comment: Do these buttons enable for any other users (such as an administrator)? If not, do any of the items ever make it to World Server? If not, it looks like the Translation Manager service is not running or failing.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for your comment. Yes buttons are enabled for the Admin but not for the regional editors with appropriate rights as noted above. And yes the items do make it to the world server.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SDL Live Content documentation titled "Resending a Translation Job (on send error":

> To resend a Translation Job you must have Translation Management
>   rights and one other Content Manager right to a Publication that is a
>   target for the translated content.

<strike>R-W doesn't sound like enough to translate from a source to a target. Try giving author *localize* permissions on the correct target (child publication) folder.</strike>

**Update**: permissions aren't needed to start translation jobs.